# Specifying a link key in android without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to determine if there is a way in android to associate a specific link key with an already existing remote bluetooth device instance.

Essentially what I want to do is create a connection with a non-discoverable bluetooth device without going through the pairing or re-pairing procedure.

I am not able to establish the link key with the device in a standard pairing procedure because I am working with a custom proprietary pairing mechanism. I would prefer to accomplish this task without using native code, but if I have to then I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no public api mechanism to associate a link key with a device without going through the pairing process.

After pairing this association is automatically created (aka bonding) once devices are bonded then further connection will re-use the link key that was generated previously.

even if device is non-discoverable you should still be able to connect bond / pair with it, if you know the device bluetooth address.

internal / private mechanism by changing the underlying android bluez code, and hooking up to feed a pre-generated link key etc is theoretically possible and it will be a difficult project and a custom solution.
that is assuming that you have the link keys to feed / associate. note - link key is a function of the device address of both devices in addition to device clock etc.
bluetooth

Comment: Yes I am aware of all of the above. Are you sure I would have to go so far as to alter the Bluez code? I was hoping to be able to accomplish this task by possibly using reflection.

I found this function in the android source that seems to be for setting the key

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#BluetoothDevice.setPasskey%28int%29

Comment: These are private APIs / wrappers that ultimately talk to the underlying BlueZ code. nothing for setting linkkey though from here.

Comment: So I would not be able to use the previously mentioned setPasskey wrapper to set the link key at all in the java api? Or are you saying this is not even the correct parameter (passkey!=link key) and everything associated with the link key is handled in BlueZ?

Comment: PassKey is not the same as Link Key, Passkey gets used to generate the Link-key. Pass keys are typically 4-6 digits , Link-keys are 16 bytes (128 bits) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing

Comment: Ahh yes just realized the parameter to the function was too short to bet the link key (int). I assumed the passkey was the same a the link key because there is another hidden function called setPin. The Pin I believed was the 4-6 digit number input upon pairing. thank you for all the help I will have to look into the source some more and see if this is feasible.

Comment: @C.ZachMartin, have you find something for writing/reading the link key in android ?

Answer (score 16):

I needed to solve this problem myself.  The crucial step was finding [this code](http://snipplr.com/view/49526/get-ibluetooth-instance/), which told me to add the android.bluetooth package to my project, and add the files IBluetooth.aidl and IBluetoothCallback.aidl (which you'll find at the link).

Once you instantiate the IBluetooth object, you have access to the BluetoothService class, and can use any of the methods in IBluetooth.aidl.  The method I was interested in was

```
setPin(String address, byte[] pin)
```

The problem with using it is the other Bluetooth code expects the pairing dialog to have been called already, and keeps track of that in a HashMap in the BluetoothEventLoop class.  If you try calling setPin() without having initiated a pairing request, you'll see an error like this:

```
setPin(<address>) called but no native data available, ignoring. Maybe the PasskeyAgent Request was cancelled by the remote device or by bluez.
```

So the workaround for me (using the Chat example) was starting the connect thread to initiate the pairing request, then sleeping 500 ms to ensure the thread had started, then calling setPin().

Comment: I was able to do this without creating the aidls, I used reflection with byte[] ar = new byte[]{0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34};Method m2 = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPin", new Class[]{Array.newInstance(byte.class,4).getClass()});
              m2.invoke(btDevice, ar);

Comment: Isn't the setPin method used to just set the pin value used during pairing and not the 128 bit link key?

Comment: You're correct - but it's an answer for "create a connection with a non-discoverable bluetooth device without going through the pairing or re-pairing procedure".

Comment: @JPM: `Array.newInstance(byte.class,4).getClass()` could be written as `byte[].class`

Comment: @hemisphire could you please elaborate on where exactly you have inserted your code in the chat example? I am using JPM's method in `BluetoothChatService.connect(device)` right after `        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
mConnectThread.start();`

like that:

`        byte[] ar = new byte[]{0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34}; //1234
        Method m2;
  try {
   Thread.sleep(500);
   m2 = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", new Class[]{Array.newInstance(byte.class,4).getClass()});
         m2.invoke(device, ar);
  }catch{ something }`

PS. For some reason formating wont work.

Comment: Yes, right after the thread is started: 

private String PIN = "ABCD"; 

try {
 Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", new Class[]{Array.newInstance(byte.class,4).getClass()}); 
 // Sleep so that the connection thread can start, which invokes the dialog
 Thread.sleep(500);
 if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setting pin to: " + PIN);
 // Now set the pin, which will make the dialog unnecessary
 m.invoke(device, PIN.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 if (D) Log.d(TAG, "set pin");

} catch (Exception e) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Exception during connecting " + e.getMessage());
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

Comment: @hemisphire in addiction to my previous comment, I'm testing with bluetooth chat sample, and as Mike said I put your code (from the comment) after mmConnectThread.start(). However, it does not work. I don't have any errors however I'm still getting the dialog on both devices. Can you please please help?

Comment: @Tiago, do you have the sleep call in?  Making sure the thread sleeps correctly is usually the problem.  If so, do you have any obvious problems you see in logcat?

Comment: @hemisphire in your code, device would be device name or device id or its object of IBluetooth?

Comment: @gIrL it's android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.  Download the sample from http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html, the method is in BluetoothChatService.java.

Comment: @hemisphire How to perform OOB mechanism for pairing through Android