# Is there a way for automatic/programatic pairing of 2 bluetooth devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an application which connects devices over bluetooth and exchanges messages. It works fine for paired devices, but I would also like it to automatically pair devices that are not paired. Like for example it could store and use the same PIN for pairing requests, I just dont know how to manage this request programatically in my applciation, how to automatically set and send the PIN when you get a pairing request and how to initiate such a request with the predefined PIN code.

Any snippets or thoughts would be highly appreciated! :)

**EDIT:**
I know its risky, I am developing this app for emergency situations only where no other means but bluetooth is available. Also is there maybe a way of premature pairing with devices without even connecting to them? Like lets say there is a list of MAC Addresses of those devices and I can use them to generate a bond with that devices so that they appear paired on my device?

Comment: Although not recommended , [here is the roundabout][1] way of doing this through reflections.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464426/specifying-a-link-key-in-android-without-pairing/5858799#5858799

Comment: thanks, since what API version is that available?

Comment: @DennisMathews I ve made a broadcast receiver to listen for PAIRING REQUESTS and used reflection to set the Pin, now whenever I am connecting to a non bonded device the pairing dialog appears on both devices simultaneously, meaning that something (probably the PIN) is passed, but the dialogs wont close and even though the console doesnt print any errors the devices do not appear bonded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflecting the setPin method allowed me to send the pin automatically to the other device. I had to implement it in a broadcast receiver that is listening for pairing requests. Although I cant get rid of the dialog it just stucks there on the screen and I dont know how to close it (programatically) and continue the bonding procedure since this dialog is called from inside connect() which is a blocking method. I am not giving up on it yet though :)

Comment: I know it's been long time ago, but have you managed to get rid of pin prompt?

Comment: As far as I remember unfortunately I didn't :(
I managed to do more with WiFi ad-hoc connections though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. To do what you want to do would create a huge security risk. Think about it, my device just comes anywhere in bluetooth range of yours and now I can send you anything I want without you knowing? You can't really do this and I highly recommend not trying to subvert it.

Comment: This would likely be limited to devices in his control (i.e. running his software,) so I don't think it would involve the risk you're mentioning.  Also, I'm sure it's possible... everything is.

Comment: @Fosco Yea, you're probably right. There probably is a way of doing this. But what ever that way is, it's highly likely that it's subversive. And yes, he's still opening himself up to security risks if he does this only with his app. His app essentially puts a chink in the entire bluetooth armor. Anyone who knows how to subvert his app then would be able to hack on a device running it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to straighten things up a little bit and got some new ones :)

Comment: I was looking for this too as a solution for blind and visually impaired people - they could automatically pair their phone with another specially programmed public transport bus and thus receive some information about an apporaching bus - bus number, route name etc. But this idea gets killed by the fact that autopairing is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

With Bluetooth version 2.1 and above there is a method of pairing called the 'just works' association model. This is the lowest security method of pairing and has no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks.

However, this will provide a secure, encrypted link without the need to exchange pin numbers or verify device ID.

The API on different platforms may differ but the underlying HCI messages require that you indicate that your device (or one of the devices) has the following IO capabilities:

```
No Keyboard, No Display.
```

As you might have guessed, this is a mode for very 
simple devices that use Bluetooth, such as a speaker or headphones.

If you can find the API to configure that, then the 'just works' association mode of Secure Simple Pairing will be used for pairing.

The next step is to store the link keys e.g. bonding. Many devices e.g. mobile phones, will still create a dialogue box to the user to ask if they want to 'remember this device', as user authorisation is specified by the BT specifications... but that's another problem.